# Social Sharing Predefined Custom Messages

Tags: php, facebook, twitter, google-plus, social-networking

I'm developing an application on my website that allows users to preform some calculations. I would like users to have the ability to share the results socially by clicking the network of their choice and already having a pre-written message with the results.

I was hoping this would be easy enough to accomplish with AddToAny API, but it looks like what I'm trying to do will only work for Twitter. If I could get something like this to work for at least Twitter, Facebook, and Google+ it would be great. Ideally I was hoping to get an app like AddToAny to do this because it's not a resource hog, and it would open up sharing to more than a few networks with a single click.

If anyone has any ideas or suggestions it would really be appreciated.

Comment: I believe with facebook you have to register your thing as an ap in order to use their api to share custom "stories." It used to be that you could just put a message in the share url but that doesn't work anymore.

Comment: prefilling is not allowed on facebook, the message always must be 100% user generated.

Comment: What @luschn mentions is true. If you wanted to do this on Facebook you might have to use Open Graph to build a custom story, and then publish the object per user. This way, custom information could be shown in your story, but people would still be able to personalize and add their own message. I would start by looking here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/getting-started